# EKS Fargate Task

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I want to execute an ECR python image in EKS Fargate cluster. The job need to run once a day at particular time. For this I am creating a task in ECS and running it in EKS cluster. Below is the step function workflow. I would like to know if this is a right approach or can we directly trigger a Fargate job in EKS without ECS.

```
{
  "Comment": "State Machine Scheduler",
  "StartAt": "CreateEksCluster",
  "States": {
    "CreateEksCluster": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::eks:createCluster.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "Name": "EKSClusterName",
        "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::accid:role/eksclusterrole",
        "ResourcesVpcConfig": {
          "SubnetIds": [
            "subnet-905a6eb",
            "subnet-0559dcc189fd18"
          ],
          "SecurityGroupIds": [
            "sg-02cc3030701b62"
          ]
        }
      },
      "Next": "SubmitRunJob"
    },
    "SubmitRunJob": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "Cluster": "EKSClusterName",
        "TaskDefinition": "arn:aws:ecs:region:id:task-definition/pythonimage:1",
        "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
        "NetworkConfiguration": {
          "AwsvpcConfiguration": {
            "Subnets": [
              "subnet-905a6eb",
              "subnet-0559dcc189fd18"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run a job directly on EKS without using ECS. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-eks.html. The documentation says, "if you want to manage other Kubernetes resources, including custom resources, use the **eks:call** service integration." Rather than calling a Job, you can call a CronJob. If you need the path, method, etc run try running kubectl create cronjob  with increased verbosity. You can do this by adding the "v" flag, e.g. -v5.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will update on this further

Comment: I used the same example as in the documentation, even after 8 mins into the execution, I dont see any jobs in EKS cluster.

Comment: The example is creating a Kubernetes Job object which doesn't have a schedule associated with it. Your original post implied that you wanted to run the job on a recurring schedule (a CronJob). Step Functions may not have permission to create objects in your cluster. I'd look at that first.